# Exclude all modules from Wildfly 10

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly

I'm trying to deploy my Spring-boot app to a wildlfy server.
However, i'm finding some conflicts between the libs.
So, i want my app to use only what i define on my pom, and completely ignore all wildfly modules.
Is it possible?

Using Wildfly 10 and spring-boot 2.x

Comment: What conflicts?

Comment: do you want to run your spring-boot app without JBoss(WildFly) modules?

Comment: @nikolas I can't be sure of wich conflicts. That's why i want to remove all modules.

Comment: @NafazBenzema yes, that's it.

Comment: have you found any alternative way? I have no idea it is possible.

Comment: @NafazBenzema not yet =/

Answer (score 2):

### Modules

Yes, it is possible. According to the [`RedHat docs`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6/html/development_guide/prevent_a_module_being_implicitly_loaded), §3.4, and according to my practice which I have tested several times: You can *PREVENT A Module being implicitly loaded*. For this:

1. Create (if not already existing) `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file and add this into that file:

   ```
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
       <deployment>
          <exclusions>
             <module name="org.javassist" />
             <module name="org.dom4j" />
             <module name="org.apache.commons.configuration" />
             <!--and so on.. -->
          </exclusions>
       </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```
2. add this (*jboss-deployment-structure.xml*) file to the project (For a web application (WAR) add this file to the WEB-INF directory. For an EJB archive (JAR) add it to the META-INF directory).

### Sub-systems

On the other hand, `EAR` files (modules) will most likely include sub-systems, like `WAR` and `JAR` files. You can exclude only sub-system, from the module, as well. For this, include this snippet in the same (*jboss-deployment-structure.xml*) file:

```
<exclude-subsystems>
  <subsystem name="SUBSYSTEM_NAME" />
</exclude-subsystems>
```

Comment: @renanleandrof please let me know if it helped you.

Comment: it helped, but i already knew that. The information i don't have is the full list of modules or submodules that i should put there, in order to delete all modules. =/

Comment: @1553537 do you know where i can find the list of all submodules to disable?

Comment: @renanleandrof there's a way to see this as well.. do you have your server locally? if it's local, you should look into `modules` directory.